# Elgato Game Capture: add a prompt to delete or save the previously recorded video before writing to disk?

Tags: c++, dll, prompt

I have Elgato Game Capture HD software. It is a free download, so I won't be providing the files contained in the program. Essentially, I want to have a prompt that asks the user if they want to delete or save the video that was previously recorded before it writes to my hard drive. I am very bad about deleting pointless content that I record; sometimes I record gameplay for hours and yet none of it is worth saving. I can write the code in C++, but I need a starting point. How do I edit the .dll files in cpp and also which .dll would need to be edited for this to work? I am a beginner in cpp but I would like to give this challenge a shot.

Comment: You're trying to do way too many things at the same time, especially for a beginner. I'd recommend reading some books first on programming in general. Also, 'editing' .dll files is called Reverse Engineering, and it's an inmensely complex subject to start with in the world of programming. Good luck.

Comment: A better idea might be to write a program that launches your capturing program and when it exits asks whether to keep the file or delete it. (This only works if you know the name of the file, of course.)

Comment: All of my gameplay is saved in the same folder everytime. Is there a way to loop and check for a new file to be added to my gameplay folder? Then I would need the program to say, "hey, buddy, you added a file, do you wanna save it or delete it?". Can this be done?